# Need logical and performance enhancement solution

Tags: asp.net, weblogic

I have developed CRM for pharmaceutical company. At time of creating reports I am getting 6000-8000 records of doctors. On that I have do some calculation.

For that I have defined a for loop on list of records I get. There are inner loops too. so my number of iteration are increasing. approximately 6000 * 16 * 2 =  3,12,000.

Obviously taking lot of time. So please help me to narrow down the process.

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: Show some dummy code .. how you designed the iteration .. so that one can help you..

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Is it classic ASP or MVC? What does you mean by "do some calculation"? what is it exactly? Where is your code, which you want to make a better?

Comment: 6000*16*2=192000. Not a huge thing if the calculations aren't bad. But as others said, what database is in use since it could probably handle that amount of data quite easily when asked.

Comment: I am working ASP.NET. Yes I have designed the iterations. My DB part is working fine. It takes more time even on my local machine. to process this data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Parallel processing? 8000 records is not really that much as long as your records aren't huge.

```
public class Doctor
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public int ImportantValue;
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doctors = Builder<Doctor>.CreateListOfSize(8000).Build();

        Parallel.ForEach(doctors, doctor => {

            // Inner loop 1
            for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                // do stuff in inner loop 1
            }

            // Inner loop 2
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                // do stuff in inner loop 1
            }
        });
}
```

Utilizing the **Parallel.For()** you can basically speed up your processing significantly by passing each object in your list to a separate thread.

As the commenters already said, it is impossible to answer your question more specifically without knowing what you're doing now. It could also be that all you need is to do some **Task/Await** stuff in your code to speed things up significantly.

Bottom Line: 8000 records of anything isn't really alot in today's computers :)

Comment: my actual process in this manner. I get a doctors list, on bases of from date to to date, I have to calculate some figures for each month specified in date range. Latter on I have to create an excel sheet for the same.